# Did Larry Barese turn rat?

Tags: the-sopranos

In the episode remember when Pauline says he hears its Larry Barese been talking, while they're watching the FBI digging up the body form the basement from a house, and near the end of the episode you hear them say Larry told them Jackie Aprile was responsible for that murder, presumably to protect Tony and Paulie, if he had not flipped why would he tell the FBI about the location of the body in the first place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He got arrested when Junior and a bunch of others did in the RICO sting and then later a while after his release he is re arrested for a new trial. Like so many of them it's hinted he gave tidbits without turning full rat (like Pussy tried to do at first). He was always loyal to Tony whilst also trying to get some kind of deal, hence offering a body so he hangs the murder on the dead Jackie and a cold case is closed. We presume this some how positively affects his case. I wouldn't call Larry Barese a rat.

Answer (score -3):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Barese):

> He is mentioned in the season 6 episode "Remember When," when the FBI
>   begins digging up a body from a murder that occurred 25 years ago
>   (Tony's first murder, which Paulie Gualtieri also played a part in).
>   **There is a minor discussion about Larry which indicates that he gave
>   the FBI the location of the body. However, in order to save Tony and
>   Paulie, after the body is recovered, he goes on to tell the FBI
>   (falsely) that the murder was committed solely by the late Jackie
>   Aprile.**

The [episode's Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remember_When_(The_Sopranos)) also doesn't contain much else than suspicions:

> **On a suspected tip from the reincarcerated capo "Larry Boy" Barese**,
>   the FBI begin investigating an old murder of a small-time bookie named
>   Willie Overall. Overall was Tony's first murder, which happened on
>   Labor Day weekend of 1982 when Tony was 22. The hit was assigned to
>   Tony by his father, DiMeo Family Capo "Johnny Boy" Soprano, and Paulie
>   Gualtieri accompanied him on it. Paulie goes to Tony's house and
>   informs him of the situation, and, after the Bureau starts digging for
>   Willie's body, Tony and Paulie pack up and drive toward Miami,
>   Florida, to lie low until the heat blows over. The FBI indeed manage
>   to find Overall's remains.
>
> [...]
>
> **Larry's misinformation about Willie Overall's murder leads the FBI to
>   blame it on the deceased Jackie Aprile, Sr.**

Comment: The OP asked *why* he told them that and if *he flipped*, though, which is currently not in the answer.